# Can't connect remotely to SQL Server 2014 on Windows Server 2012 R2

Tags: sql-server, networking, sql-server-2012, ssms

I am trying to install SQL Server 2014 on Windows Server 2012 R2. I can connect locally using windows authentication and sql server authentication, but when I try to connect remotely using hostname\instance, I get error:

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while
>   establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or
>   was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that
>   SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL
>   Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance
>   Specified) (.Net SqlClient Data Provider)

In SQL Server Network Configuration I have shared memory and tcp/ip enabled and named pipes disabled.

http://snag.gy/GHY8X.jpg

Under TCP/IP Protocol, I have Enabled=Yes, Keep Alive=30000, and Listen All=Yes

http://snag.gy/kL5vK.jpg

Under IP Addresses, I have

http://snag.gy/lgoD6.jpg

The Windows Firewall is turned off (for now).  The machines are not part of a domain just p2p workgroup.

The client machine is XP SP3 pro. I tried connecting using SMSS and odbc, but both failed.

Don't know if it is relevant, but I ran sp_readerrorlog on the server and I saw this in the logs

> The SQL Server Network Interface library could not register the
>   Service Principal Name (SPN) [ MSSQLSvc/SERVER_2012:49184 ] for the
>   SQL Server service. Windows return code: 0xffffffff, state: 63.
>   Failure to register a SPN might cause integrated authentication to use
>   NTLM instead of Kerberos. This is an informational message. Further
>   action is only required if Kerberos authentication is required by
>   authentication policies and if the SPN has not been manually
>   registered.

Sql Browser is enabled and running.

Allow remote connections to this server is checked.

Answer (score 2):

Turns out it was the firewall. I had only disabled the firewall for domain not for private network.